# E(x) for uniform distribution

Tags: expected-value, continuous-data, probability-calculus

I would like to take a uniform distribution for example. Let’s say a train will arrive at the station randomly within every 10 minute window, so the probability density function is $f(t)=0.1$,$\: t \in (0,10)$.
The expected average waiting time for a traveller is

$\int_0^{10} 0.1t \,dt \text{ minutes } = 5 \text{ minutes }$

But as we know, the probability for a single point (for example $t$ is exactly $2$ minutes) is zero, so $0\times 0+0.1\times 0+...+2\times 0+2.1\times 0+...+9.9\times 0+10\times 0=0$, any real number from the interval $(0,10)$ times its single point probability is $0$, so how come the expected average $E(t)$ is $5$ minutes?

Comment: On the other hand, if you measure time only to the nearest minute -- ignoring the "second hand" on your watch which as you know is actually the third hand -- and assume that the $11$ values $0,1,2,\dots, 9, 10$ are equally likely to be recorded, then the average time is $5$ minutes, no?

Answer (score 5):

Think about the center of mass of a uniformly dense, thin rod of length 10 inches. (It's at 5 inches along the length.)

Now think about the amount of mass between 5 and 5.1 inches from the left end. Now think about  the amount of mass between 5 and 5.01 inches. Now the mass between 5 and 5.0000000000001 inches. Keep going adding zeroes...  clearly the amount of mass at *exactly* 5 inches will be 0.

And if you make any finite (or even countable) list of point-values and add all the masses at those points, they'll still add to 0. It's *intervals* of the length that have mass.

Yet every point along the length has something which tells us about how *dense* the object is there (about the rate at which mass is added for a tiny change in $x$) -- the *density*.

So how do we work out how much mass is in an interval of the rod? We can integrate the density function over the interval.

Continuous probability densities work the same way.

[You seem to have informed an intuitive sense that you should be able to work out an expectation for a continuous variate by summing the density at some list of values, but you can't.]

---

You seem to want to write $E(X)$ in terms of a limit of a sum and the way you do it doesn't work.

This can be done but you have to do it the right way.

Since for continuous variables probability is defined only on intervals I'll define our sum in terms of probabilities of laying in intervals.

If $f_X(x)$ is sufficiently "nice" we could evaluate $xf$ over a grid of values and use those to approximate the required expectation (i.e. we could use a form of [Riemann integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral)). If we have a set of points $x_0,x_1,...,x_n$ which define a set of intervals over the region we want the expectation in, then the probability that $X$ lies in the interval $(x_{i-1},x_i)$ is approximately $f(x_i) (x_i-x_{i-1})$ (note the similarity to $f(x)dx$.

Then we can write the expectation as an approximate sum:

$E(X) \approx \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i f(x_i) (x_i-x_{i-1})$

(by taking $t_i=x_i$ when looking at the definitions at the above link). This approximates the required integral for the expectation and in the limit (as you take a set of grids such that the largest gap between adjacent $x$'s goes to $0$, you will get the expectation you seek.

[Your difficulty appears to be that you keep trying to replace $f(x_i) (x_i-x_{i-1})$ by something like $P(X=x_i)$ but you can't because that's not a way to approximate the probability of being in any interval.]

There are many other ways to define integrals, but I mention the Riemann because it's one you're most likely to have at least seen before being expected to do integration. You might have been taught a slightly different formulation of integration.

Comment: I understand only the probability only exists for aninterval, but the E(x) requires the exact number(like 3,4.2 etc rather than 3 to 4.2)  multiply by its probability , so ultimately the summation will be 0? or can I think in this way: dx is a extremely small interval, so 3* P(3) ~= 3*f(3)*dx?

Comment: No, you've gone straight back to doing the thing I explained was wrong -- $E(X)$ is defined as an integral not a sum of values at a list of points within the interval. That is, for a continuous distribution, $E(X)$ is *not* $\sum x\,p_x$.If you want to think in terms of $dx$'s you *still* have to do it for an interval. The probability of being in the interval between $x$ and $x+dx$ is $f(x)dx$.

Comment: Whether you have discrete values from x1 to x2 (ex: 1,2,3,4) or a continuous interval from x1 to x2 (where each step is infinitesimal) does not matter. It's the same thing, they are both intervals. Say you've a dice with 6 sides. The probability of getting 1 is 1/6, 2 is 1/6 and so forth. The E(X) is 3.5. What you are wondering is, as I understand it, why the probability of gaining an 8 on a dice is 0 while the E(X) remains the same!

Comment: $\int_{2}^{2.1}xf(x)dx=2*f(2)*0.1$

Comment: @whoisit Well, that's at best approximately true for general $f$, but for a constant $f$ in the interval, yes, that would be true.

Comment: @Glen-b   sorry I couldn't edit the previous comment  $\int_{2}^{2.1}xf(x)dx=2*f(2)*0.1$    let's assume 0.1 as a very small interval(though it is not), so why we use f(2) rather than f(2.1)?I think it's because as the dx=0.1 is very small, so we can assume f(2)~=f(2.1). As you mentioned that The probability of being in the interval between x and x+dx is f(x)dx rather than f(x+dx)dx, so can I say as dx  is a very small interval that can be treated as single point probability, that's why we could multiply by its exact value at that point where x=2?

Comment: As to why $f(x)$ rather than $f(x+\delta x)$ (or anything in between) ... when approximating the integral in an interval -- *any* $f(t_i)$ in the interval $x_i\leq t_i\leq x_{i+1}$ will work for the ordinary sort of problems you're going to be dealing with (see the Riemann integral which I linked to before). That's really about how integration works and isn't much to do with stats (see math.SE). The difficulty was that you tried to use a probability at a point rather than the density, and density is not probability.

Comment: @Glen_b, I understand dx is actually an interval, so 1. The probability for the dx interval exists ie f(x)dx is a probability for the interval( density multiply by interval). 2. As the dx is very small, so f(x)dx can be treated as the probability between x and x+dx, since dx is almost to 0, f(x)d(x) could be treated as the probability at the point x(this is just for understanding and intergration purposes, actually the probability for any single point is 0), am I correct on 1 and 2?

Comment: $(x,x+dx)$ is an interval. 1. Right. 2. "$f(x)d(x)$ *could be treated as the probability at the point* $x$"  --- well, no.

Answer (score 3):

E(X) would be

[image]

The [Probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) calculates  what the probability of **a** value relative to the other values in a given interval is, in your case [0, 10].

[Cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) is the probability of **all** the values "to the left" of a point in a given interval.

So, there's a difference in how you calculate the probability at a single point and all the values to "the left". E(X) is based on all the values.